# Can I get the current HTML or Uri for the Metro WebView control?

Tags: xaml, webview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

It doesn't appear that the Source property for the XAML WebView control is updating as the user is navigating in the WebView.  Is it possible to get either the current Uri or the HTML currently being rendered in the WebView?  My need is to parse the HTML that is being displayed so either would work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that the WebView doesn't provide a way to retrieve its HTML directly. But you can use WebView.InvokeScript like this:

```
webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] {"document.documentElement.outerHTML;"})
```

You can also obtain the Uri via the LoadCompleted event's NavigationEventArgs.Uri.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the LoadCompleted event for WebView? That gives the URI that's just loaded.

Answer (score -1):

The property you are looking for is called `Source`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.source.aspx

Unluckily the `Document` property of WinForms `WebBrowser` doesn't seem to exist anymore.
You will have to re-download the page and process it using libraries like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/)/[FizzlerEx](http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I'll look again but it didn't look like the Source property was updating as the user clicked on links.

Comment: Question is about Metro/Windows 8 or UWP apps, not WinForms

Comment: I only mentioned `WinForms` to point out the difference between the old and new `WebBrowser` (WinForms vs XAML). The `Source` property is still a viable option.