# Get the navigating url in webview WinRt

Tags: javascript, webview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am injecting this JS to get the `navigating url` (`destination`) at run time. I am getting JS exceptions. What is wrong?

```
     static String NAVIGATING_FUNCTION = "window.onbeforeunload = function(){ window.external.notify(' + location.href + ''); };";
     webView.InvokeScript("eval", new String[] { NAVIGATING_FUNCTION });
```

Also please tell me how to `cancel the navigation` and return back to the previous page using this JS?

Comment: Your quotes at the end of your function are messed up; try pasting into an editor to correct them. In addition, if you want to cancel navigation, try `return false` at the end of your `onbeforeunload` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, since I haven't used the WebView (yet), you want to report the current location before leaving and then cancel it?

You could try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ window.external.notify(location.href); return false; };
```

I am not sure why you had quotes in there; `location.href` would be in that web view, and it would be passed as a string.

Also, take a look at the responses to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/ac390a6a-d4ad-408c-8b13-93f9694cbabe). One of them says:

> Did you get your problem solved?  In the Release Preview, you need to
>   add some code that looks like this:

```
        List<Uri> allowedUris = new List<Uri>();
        allowedUris.Add(e.Uri);
        allowedUris.Add(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
        Browser.AllowedScriptNotifyUris = allowedUris;
```

Another thing, this thread: [Can I get the current HTML or Uri for the Metro WebView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597232/can-i-get-the-current-html-or-uri-for-the-metro-webview-control?rq=1), talks about the LoadCompleted event handler.

See if that helps.

Comment: instead of the current location I want the to know the destination before navigation and cancel the navigation. Is that possible?

Comment: Doesn't appear so. "unfortunately there doesn’t seem to be a way to extract the target url, nor to be able to cancel the navigation, unlike the real Navigating event that the WebBrowser control has" -- from http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2012/04/21/Limitations-of-the-WebView-in-Windows-8-Metro-Apps.aspx