# windows phone 8.1 webview loaded document source code

Tags: html, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I need to get source code of web page which "loaded" on webview. Is there any way of doing this ?

I tried it on Windows Form Application. I can reach data easily with this :

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText
```

But in windows phone 8.1 i can't do this.

Comment: You may to it from "inside" the WebView using InvokeScript and just Output it via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use InvokeScriptAsync method.

```
string html = await webBrowser1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
```

Answer based on [Can I get the current HTML or Uri for the Metro WebView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597232/can-i-get-the-current-html-or-uri-for-the-metro-webview-control)